# create a xml layout for activity in center with borders surrounded in tablet view

Tags: android

how to create a xml layout for activity in center with borders surrounded in tablet view like picture linked here: (specified in red)

[xml layout](http://andriman.com/temp/xmlLayoutView.jpg)

I want to place my activity in center and two columns in sides
is there a standard way to create this layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#f5f5f5" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000" />
    <!-- Activity layout -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#f5f5f5" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Just replace color code in background to get your desired display.[image]

Comment: hi, how to add shadow to border?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197892/add-shadow-to-custom-shape-on-android/14720283#14720283 to add shadow to border.