# Failed to show Vertical Line in android using View?

Tags: android, xml, draw, shapes

can someone pls guide me what should i need to add in code to draw vertical lines of fixed height i want vertical lines like a scale measurement in this url [see vertical line example](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=3DC6681F40C57DF4&resid=3DC6681F40C57DF4%218271&app=WordPdf)
Here is my code [TRIED CODE](http://pastie.org/9448117)

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >
<LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/linear_layout_one"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">


       <View
android:layout_width="5dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:rotation="90"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
   <View
android:layout_width="5dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:rotation="90"
android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"/>
   <View
android:layout_width="5dip"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:rotation="90"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

   <View
android:layout_width="5dip"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:rotation="90"
android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"/>

   <View
android:layout_width="5dip"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:rotation="90"
android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"/>

   <View
android:layout_width="5dip"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:rotation="90"
android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"/>

   <View
android:layout_width="5dip"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:rotation="90"
android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"/>

   <View
android:layout_width="5dip"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:rotation="90"
android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"/>

   <View
android:layout_width="5dip"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:rotation="90"
android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"/>

   <View
android:layout_width="5dip"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:rotation="90"
android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"/>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Under this link I found document with pretty nice UI for BMI API. But still I don't understand what do you mean. You would like to divide those views with this line or what?

Comment: yes i would like to divide those views with this line but  i dnt think it will be appropriate .can u suggest me anyother way for its UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply different styles using drawable resource
See something like this [Add shadow to custom shape on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197892/add-shadow-to-custom-shape-on-android)