# How to make drop shadow for shape in Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to design a shape so that it has a drop shadow like on the picture below(that login shape).

[image]

Comment: did you tried using cardview and giving elevation to some 16.

Comment: It may help to resolve your issue. Check this [drop shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197892/add-shadow-to-custom-shape-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this [github project](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-materialshadowninepatch) by including dependency

```
compile 'com.h6ah4i.android.materialshadowninepatch:materialshadowninepatch:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "gradient",the "gradientRadius="30" is you view high, color "10" is alpha value.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
<gradient 
    android:startColor="#10ff0000"
    android:endColor="#10ffffff"
    android:centerX="0.5"
    android:centerY="0.5"
    android:gradientRadius="30"
    android:type="radial"
    />
```