# Change color of shadow for an ImageView on Android

Tags: android, shadow

I tried to drop a shadow on an ImageView according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3580051/1192499). Does anyone know how to change the color of the shadow. I need to do this using a color code and not in xml. Anyone?