# what is the use of shadow

Tags: android, shadow, thumbnails

What is the use of shadow in Android?
How do I implement shadow in thumbnails?
If someone has a sample screenshot, do you mind sharing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shadows can be added to [TextViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:shadowColor) through XML or programmatically.

If you'r wanting to add a shadow to a standard view (or any subclasses) [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567312/android-drop-shadow-on-view) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: can you use shadow in thumbnails video. possible or not

Comment: I think so, if you store the video thumbnail as an image you could then use this method to set a shadow layer:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setShadowLayer%28float,%20float,%20float,%20int%29

Comment: yes now i retrieve video is thumbnails in gallery...i want to create shadow for that thumbnails (images)..when i click the thumbnails that video will play...so i want fix this shadow function also....my questions write or wrong because i new android application...dont mistake me....

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what are your objects could be tricky. you can define what's the background in the picture and filter it, then you can strech your image in the direction of the shadow. now filter everything but the background, so you've got 3 layers - background, shadows and objects. place the shadows on the background and on top of that the objects.