# How to put shadow on button and change shadow Blur in android?

Tags: android, android-design-library

I am trying to create a view with custom shadow blur and shadow X and Y values .

Using the below code , we can put shadow on car view but how can we change blur and X and Y position .

```
app:cardElevation="2dp"
```

*This is x and y and blur amount*

[image]

Button should look like :

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333529/how-to-provide-shadow-to-button please check this link. It may help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567312/android-drop-shadow-on-view this one is also good

Comment: @Dhiru : How did you solve this ?